# How to apply custom size to text field in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, form-helpers

I am writing a form with three text input fields. I have used `text_field_tag` to create them

```
<%= text_field_tag(:input_first) %>
<%= text_field_tag(:input_second) %>
<%= text_field_tag(:input_first) %>
```

Am using bootstrap css. I want to make the second input larger than the first and the third input. How can I achieve that?

I have tried the below, and even more and the input field size is not changing.

first

```
<%= text_field_tag(:input_second, :input_html => { :class => "input-large"})  %>
```

second

```
<%= text_field_tag(:input_second, nil, :class => "input-large")  %>
```

third

```
<%= text_field_tag(:input_second, nil, :size=> 30)  %>
```

fourth

```
<span class="input-large">
 <%= text_field_tag(:input_second) %>
</span>
```

What wrong am I doing? Am a beginner in rails/css/html
ps: should I use text_field_tag or text_field ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bootstrap utilizes specific classes to control the width of input elements:

[image]

In a Rails template, you'd invoke a `text_field_tag` in the following manner:

```
<%= text_field_tag('input_second', nil, class: 'input-large') %>
```